# Set value of a switch with Firestore boolean

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a test app that switches a boolean value in Firestore. I need the app to retrieve the initial value of the switch from Firestore. Through my method, I get the error type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'bool'. The Boolean value is called LEDOn. Here is my app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final db = Firestore.instance;

  void updateLED(bool newValue) async {
    await db
        .collection('LEDStatus')
        .document('LEDStatus')
        .updateData({'LEDOn': newValue});
  }

  Future<dynamic> checkLEDStatus() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
        await db.collection('LEDStatus').document('LEDStatus').get();
    return snapshot.data['LEDOn'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Thingspeak'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Switch(
                value: checkLEDStatus(),
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    print(newValue);
                    updateLED(newValue);
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a FutureBuilder. Also, change your `checkLEDStatus()` return type to `Future<bool>`.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: checkLEDStatus(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        bool result = snapshot.data;
        return Switch(value: result, onChanged: (bool newVal) {
          setState(() => result = newVal);
          updateLED(newVal);
        });
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` widget has the property `value` which takes a value of type `bool`. Currently in your code you are returning a `Future` and that's why you get that error.  It should be like this:

```
Switch(
  value: isSwitched,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      isSwitched = value;
    });
  },
```

---

You can retrieve the boolean value from firestore inside the `initState` and then assign it to the property `value`. Then when the user switches inside `setState()` call the update method and do `isSwitched = newValue`